# How do I merge two versions of a non-text file with git?

Tags: git, merge, binary

I'm working on a project where various test parameters are stored in [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) `.ods` spreadsheet files. Problem: if two developers make changes to an `.ods` file on their branches then when we try to merge Git will (not surprisingly) throw up its hands in dismay, requiring that we choose one or the other version.

What I'd like to do is to open the two source versions of the conflicted file in LibreOffice, manually edit them into a new file, and then check in that new file as the "merged" file. This would work for any Git-opaque type of file which could be opened in some specialized editor and manually edited.

How can I do this?

Note 1: There's a ["Manual File Re-merging"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_manual_remerge) procedure described in the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/), but it still seems to presume that we're dealing with text. For example, I don't see how the command `git merge-file -p hello.ours.odb hello.common.odb hello.theirs.odb > hello.odb` could do anything intelligent with three source spreadsheet files to produce the output spreadsheet file.

Note 2: It isn't useful to argue about whether it's wise to store data in `.ods` files; there are good reasons for us to store data this way, with the overriding one being "that's the way it is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODF is a zipped-xml format; I haven't really tried, but it occurs to me you could unzip the documents, e.g. `xmllint --format content.xml` and try text-merging the results. The smoketest for this works, for me, it's

```
set -- `git checkout-index --stage=all path/to/my/foo.ods`
7z x -obase $1
7z x -oours $2
7z x -otheirs $3

find base ours theirs -name \*.xml -execdir xmllint --format {} -o {}.pretty \;

git merge-file {ours,base,theirs}/content.xml.pretty
# or not, but doing the merge-file is helpful, then
vimdiff {ours,base,theirs}/content.xml.pretty
```

to make the `ours` pretty versions look like you want. You'll have to eyeball any media file changes. Then

```
find ours -name \*.pretty -execdir -rename .pretty '' {} + 
(cd ours;7z -t zip u ../$4 .)
```

my libreoffice 6 install opens the updated versions just fine.  I don't know how awful the merges will be for major surgery, I know for my little one-pager ledger the diffs looked right for the changes I made, and merge-file's automerge  worked right, flagging the conflicts and incorporating the uns into the ours version.

Comment: **Boy**, would that be lovely. I'm guessing that it would be too error-prone, though, especially as we're dealing with multiple sheets and rearrangement of cells.

Comment: Yah, xml is so lard-laden it's difficult to find the actual content, and there's not room on the screen enough of it to see the content structure in all the bleeping "markup". Maybe if there was an editor as good as vim but able to hide the uninteresting bits with better granularity than vim's line-based folds.

Comment: Also, have you considered doing it in reverse?  Have a native text format for the parameters, and actual to-ods and from-ods converters for convenience in wrangling?  `soffice $(ods-from-parameters myparms.paramdata)` and such.  The xml's ugly and larded as sin, but it looks pretty easy to construct, just how complicated is your structure?

Comment: The structure is more messy than complicated, with data in one place being referenced by data in another place (by text match, not by spreadsheet reference), and multiple disparate blocks of data on each sheet. Not the way I'd have designed it, but again: "that's the way it is".

Answer (score 1):

> What I'd like to do is to open the two source versions of the conflicted file in LibreOffice ...

This is where you're going wrong: there aren't two source versions that are conflicted, there are *three* source versions, with *changes* (which may or may not conflict).

Git cannot compute the changes on its own because they are not plain-text lines.  But Git *can* give you the three files.  That's what a [custom merge driver](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver) is about.

The *merge base* version of the file (which the link above refers to as `%O`, with O standing for Original) will, by definition, not match the local/left-hand/`--ours` version of the file (which the link above refers to as `%A`).  It will, by definition, also not match the remote/right-hand/`--theirs` version of the file (which the link above refers to as `%B`).  The left and right versions won't match either: that's why a merge is required.  If the left and right versions did match, Git would assume that either one would serve equally well, and simply use either the left or right version (you would not be able to tell which one Git used, since they match, bit-for-bit!).

> ... manually edit them into a new file, and then check in that new file as the "merged" file. This would work for any Git-opaque type of file which could be opened in some specialized editor and manually edited.

You can in fact do this, even without defining a custom merge driver—in fact, the only point to defining the custom merge driver is to let this happen automatically, via software, without requiring getting our [grubby protuberances](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0811833/quotes/qt1346181) in there.  When the merge stops with a merge conflict, Git has left all three versions of the file in the index, in stages 1 (the merge base), 2 (the left / `--ours` version), and 3 (the right / `--theirs` version).

[The `git mergetool` script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-mergetool.sh) contains a rather complicated example of how to extract each of the three versions from the index and then run some merge tool on the extracted files.  See in particular [the `checkout_staged_file` function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a4ee44448fe98dcd8f1db9e43729ac67fc80e031/git-mergetool.sh#L230-L241) and [its callers](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a4ee44448fe98dcd8f1db9e43729ac67fc80e031/git-mergetool.sh#L304-L306).  Your job will be to extract the three versions, do your hand merge by hand, and then `git add` the resulting binary object as the resolved version of the file.